# How to prove that a point is not local maximum or local minimum of the function $f(x,y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I was faced with this question:

> Given that $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3-3x^2+6y^2+3x-12y+8$. 
> Prove that $(1,2)$ is a critical point of $f$, and that it's not a local minimum or a local maximum.

It's my first time dealing with a question like this, I have found the point and found that $f_{xx}f_{yy} - (f_{xy})^2 = 0$. 
And now I need to prove that it's not maximum or minimum, how do I do that? The only way I thought about is just substituting points until I get $f(x,y) > f(1,2)$ and another point $f(x,y) < f(1,2)$. 
But that obviously isn't an efficient way and might be wrong. 
I would appreciate any help in how to deal with this question and questions like these in general whenever I get a point that isn't a min/max/saddle, how can I decide what point is it?

Comment: As Hessian test is inconclusive, you can try and rewrite it in a form such that it is easier to analyze the function in the neighborhood of $(1, 2)$. But that is not always simple. In that case, my suggestion is to plug in value of $x$ or $y$ so you are left with equation in one variable. Then it is simpler to analyze points in the neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)=(x-1)^3-(y-2)^3+1$ and $f(1,2)=1$.

For any $\varepsilon>0$

- $f(1+\varepsilon,2)=1+\varepsilon^3>f(1,2)$.
- $f(1,2+\varepsilon)=1-\varepsilon^3<f(1,2)$.

So "near" $(1,2)$ you always can find points above and below $f(1,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

On the vertical line $x=1$, we have
$$
f(x,y)=f(1,y)=-y^3+6y^2-12y+9=-(y-2)^3+1
$$
which is strictly decreasing, hence $f$ does not have a local min or max at $(1,2)$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I'm not getting the idea of why this makes $(1,2)$ not a local max/min. if the function $f(1,y)=g(y)$ you provided is strictly decreasing, doesn't that mean $1$ is it's maximum? which means $(1,2)$ is a local maximum. Could you explain the idea once more please?

Comment: @Pwaol: Since $f(1,y)$ is strictly decreasing, $f(1,y) > f(1,2)$ for all $y < 2$, and $f(1,y) < f(1,2)$ for all $y > 2$.